# How to round to any number in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, rounding

I am in the middle of making a calculator in C# and I want to round to nearest 1, 10, 100, etc and also like nearsest 0.1, 0.001, etc. I have seen other projects that tell me how to do it but I tried and they don't seem to work.

I've tried:

```
textBox1.Text = Convert.ToString(Math.Round(Convert.ToDouble(Label1.Text), Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text), MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero));
```

and...

```
textBox1.Text = Convert.ToString(Math.Round(Convert.ToDouble(Label1.Text), Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text)));
```

and...

```
textBox1.Text = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt32(Label1.Text) / Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text) * Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text));
```

Comment: Pleae be more specific then "does not work". What is happening or not happening? Also note that the only price you get for squezing many operations into one line, is a terrible time during debugging. Use Temproary variables and one ordewr per line to localize exceptions better.

Comment: An off topic comment: When processing input from users, consider using `Double.TryParse` instead of `Convert.ToDouble`.  Users often type things incorrectly (like the site I was just at that threw an exception when I copied the "Invoice total" from their invoice into the field labeled "Invoice total", and it didn't like "$").  With `TryParse`, you can gracefully handle errors (though not if all your code is on a single line).  You might also consider using `decimal` rather than `double` for your numbers.  They are more "exact"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Math.Round](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.round?view=netframework-4.7.2) has overloads that allow you to round to a particular decimal.

e.g.

```
Math.Round(0.05, 1, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
```

will result in 0.1

If you want to round to the nearest 10, 100, etc, you will need to do a bit more math.

```
Math.Round((double)50 / 100, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero) * 100;
```

results in 100, for rounding to the nearest hundred, while

```
Math.Round((double)55 / 10, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero) * 10;
```

will get you to the nearest 10, in this case 60.

Comment: but how would you round a decimal as well

Answer (score 0):

You can make an Extension method to do it, using the same idea from Jonathon's answer. You divide the input by the interval you choose, round it using `Math.Round`, and then multiply the rounded number by the interval.

```
static class Extensions
{
    public static int RoundToInterval(this int i, int interval)
    {
        if (interval == 0)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("The specified interval cannot be 0.", nameof(interval));
        }
        return ((int)Math.Round((double)i / (double)interval)) * interval;
    }
}
```

Calling it will look like so.

```
int input = 13;
var result = input.RoundToInterval(10);
```

The result of the previous example call will be `10`. Change `input` to 16, and the result will be `20`. If you pass 100 as the argument to `RoundToInterval`, the result will be `0`, and 51 (and 50 with the default MidpointRounding choice) will give the result of `100`.

Comment: You could make the interval value optional, with a default of 1. May want to throw an argument exception if the value provided is 0 to avoid dividing by 0 and getting a cast error from Infinity.

Comment: What about decimals?